# How do I express $4 - 2\cos^2x$ in terms of $\cos2x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> How do I express $4 - 2\cos^2x$ in terms of $\cos2x$?

I know that the identities corresponding to $\,\cos2x\,$ are:

$$\cos^2 x-\sin^2x$$
$$2\cos^2x - 1$$
$$1 - 2\sin^2x$$

I have tried to come up with a method of expressing this but I'm not getting the right answer.

$ 4 - 2(1-\sin^2x) $

$ 4 - 2 + 2\sin^2x $

$ 2 + 2\sin^2x $

Can anyone guide me on a different approach to the question? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome here! You can use the identity `2cos^2(x)=1+cos(2x)`

Comment: $4-2\cos^2x=-(2\cos^2x-1)+3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$4-2\cos^2x = 3 -2 \cos^2x +1$$
$$=3 -(2 \cos^2x-1) = 3 - \cos 2x.$$

Comment: It could be a comment !